# How do I pull coordinates from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would i go about pulling coordinates such as

20.0000,-30.0000
Or
20.0000000, 67.0000000

From a string such where they may be in the beginning, middle or end of the string? I will never know the length, or if it has a space between the coordinate set. I know that they will all have 2 period's and a comma. I am lost as to where i should start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have whitespace between the start and end of the coordinates and the erst of the string, this regex should work:

```
/\s(-?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{0,15}),\s(-?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{0,15})\s/
```

This looks for surrounding whitespace, and then matches a range of numbers including valid coordinates (up to `180` then 15 decimal points). It also includes optional minus signs.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to regex and the like. Do you know of a decent place to learn it?

Comment: [This](https://regexone.com) is decent. There's also lots of references and testing applications available.